# App Crashes when using image_picker in flutter while using release apk

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using `image_picker` package for selecting video from gallery. When I am debugging it and developing it in android studio, it works fine but when I build an apk and use it, it crashes. Well, if i select any video directly frmo the screen, it opens for me, it works fine, but when i go to gallery and then pick a video, it crashes. How can I check what is the problem?

PS: It only crashes in some specific phones, not on every device.

Update:

The code is as simple as this:

```
XFile? res = await ImagePicker().pickVideo(source: ImageSource.gallery);
```

And here are my permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

Comment: Which version of `image_picker` are you using? Seems to be a known issue in older Android versione (9, API 28): https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/87896

Comment: First of all post some code you've made. Second: Have you specified all permissions that needed for